# Make mechanical switch panel smart (or how to electronically push buttons)

Tags: transistors, switches, esp32

I do have a control panel in our camper van. It has four push buttons to turn on and off certain functions. I now want to add an ESP32 to make this panel smart and allow me to remotely control the switches (...well, more the functions attached to it).

Three of them are pretty easy:

It looks like the output of the switch is pulled-up to 3.3V. When you push the switch, it will pull to ground (they also use some kind of Microcontroller). The current when the switch is closed is somewhere in the uA range.

"All" I need to do is pulling the switch output to ground using my Microcontroller. I think it would be a bad idea to connect "my" Microcontroller directly.

So I guess I need a transistor in between. The output pin of "my" Microcontroller goes to the Base of the transistor and the emitter and collector are used to "close the circuit" for the switch to ground.

I know the some basics of transistors, but I'm struggling here. What transistor should I choose (NPN or PNP) and what resistors do I need?

The main switch - also a push button - is a bit more complicated. It's switching the "output" of the push button to 12V. So instead of pulling to ground like above, I would need to switch it the 12V+ using a transistor.

Thanks for your help....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Vehicles should be roadworthy if someone is going to use them. Inserting lousy hobby constructions to the electric circuitry rarely increases the roadworthiness. Think possible consequences of poor connections, short circuits and the unavailability of the functions when they are needed. Anything which is reliable in a vehicle is totally different than a construction which may work and stay alive in easy environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pulling 3V3 to gnd you don’t need and extra transistor, just pull with mcu pin. If you want to use an external transistor anyway use this:

[image]

For switching 12V use this circuit:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help. I'll give it a try....